# Accessing button in repeater control

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I'm trying - quite unsuccessfully - to access a button inside a repeater control. I have a repeater set up on a page that displays movies that are currently showing in cinemas. I have created two buttons and added them to the repeater - one for trailer and another for review. For the review I want to link to another page which will have another repeater with paging enabled. When a users clicks the review button they should be brought to a page that shows only the reviews for that specific movie. This is that code I have:

**MARKUP:**
The repeater:

```
   <asp:Repeater ID="movies" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <table width="641px">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <span style="font-weight:bold;font-size:16px;">
                    <%# Container.DataItem("MovieTitle")%>
                        </span>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <span style="float:right;">
                    <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl = '<%# Eval("Total")%>' style="width:80px;height:14px;"/>
                   </span>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <hr style="height:1px;border-bottom:none;color:#e3e3e3;"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
            </table>
        <table width="641px">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:Image ID="Image2" runat="server" ImageUrl = '<%# Eval("MovieImageFileName")%>' style="width:180px;height:108px;border:1px solid #e3e3e3;"/>
                </td>
                <td style="vertical-align:top;">
                    <%# Container.DataItem("Synopsis")%>
                </td>
            </tr>
            </table>
        <table width="641px">

            <tr>
                <td>
                    <span style="float:right">
                    <asp:Button ID="btnTrailer" runat="server" Text="Trailer" BackColor="#FF9900" ForeColor="White" />&nbsp;
                    <asp:Button ID="btnReview" runat="server" Text="Review" BackColor="#FF9900" ForeColor="White" CommandName="Review" />
                    </span>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <hr style="height:1px;border-bottom:none;color:#e3e3e3;"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

**CodeBehind:**

```
Dim movie_title As String
Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim myConn As New OleDbConnection
    Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand
    Dim dr, aDataReader As OleDbDataReader
    Dim query, movieID As String
    movie_title = Request.QueryString("id")
    myConn = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source = " & _
                Server.MapPath("/App_Data/MovieBoard.accdb"))
    myConn.Open()
    Dim sqlQuery = "Select movieID From Movies"
    Dim aCmd = New OleDbCommand(sqlQuery, myConn)
    aDataReader = aCmd.ExecuteReader()

    If aDataReader.Read() = True Then
        movieID = aDataReader(0)
    Else
        movieID = "0"
    End If

    query = ("Select MovieTitle, Genre, Synopsis, Starring, Total, Director, MovieImageFileName From Movies, MovieReviews, MReviewRatings WHERE Movies.MovieID = MovieReviews.MovieID AND MovieReviews.MReviewID = MReviewRatings.MReviewID AND ReviewerTypeID = 1")
    cmd = New OleDbCommand(query, myConn)
    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader()
    movies.DataSource = dr
    movies.DataBind()
End Sub

Protected Sub movies_ItemCommand(source As Object, e As RepeaterCommandEventArgs)   Handles movies.ItemCommand
    If e.CommandName = "Review" Then
        Response.Redirect("testingreviews.aspx?id = '" & movie_title)
    End If
End Sub
```

When I run page the page displays but when I click the review button I get the following error:

```
Invalid postback or callback argument.  Event validation is enabled using <pages enableEventValidation="true"/> 
in configuration or <%@ Page EnableEventValidation="true" %> in a page.  For security purposes, this feature verifies that arguments to postback or 
callback events originate from the server control that originally rendered them.  If the data is valid and expected, use the ClientScriptManager.
RegisterForEventValidation method in order to register the postback or callback data for validation.
```

Anyone any ideas on what I am doing wrong? I am very new to asp.net.

Comment: Aren't you getting syntax error for using the variable movie_title in the movies_ItemCommand event handler?

Comment: I did Manish. I have now declared it outside the page_load but still getting the error above.

Comment: Could you please post your repeater control aspx part and the "//other stuff" code?

Comment: hi Manish, I have just updated the post to include all code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to access a button use the event ItemCreated or maybe its ItemDataBound.

Handles movies.ItemCreated

In that event you can then refeer to the button using FindControl,

Something like this

```
Sub Movies_ItemDataBound(Sender As Object, e As RepeaterItemEventArgs) Handles movies.ItemDataBound
      Dim Btn As Button = CType(e.Item.FindControl("ButtonName"),Button)
End Sub
```